# Force compile time error when specialized template function is invoked

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, partial-specialization

I have a template function.  It has well defined semantics so long as the argument is not a pointer type.  If someone calls this function passing an argument of type pointer I want to force a compile time error.  I have no trouble writing the general (legal) template and the corresponding partially specialized (illegal) version.  I just cannot figure out how to defer an error from function definition to function invocation.

Comment: language? c++98? c++03? c++11? compiler Boost/TR1 libraries available?

Comment: cheers (in the - better late than never department?) I gathered that from the vanishing accept. No problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specialize it, actually.  Just add this in your function body:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!boost::is_pointer<T>()::value);
```

This will cause a failure which should be fairly easy to understand.

Comment: as usual with c++, there are several good answers :-). Nice, simple, solution.

Comment: Yup John!  That is exactly what I did.  Works like a charm.  I look forward to std::static_assert and being able to provide a clear diagnostic string.

Answer (score 4):

Using C++0x: (see it live on http://ideone.com/ZMNb1)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
    void cannot_take_pointer(T ptr)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>::value, 
        "cannot_take_pointer requires non-pointer argument");
    std::cout << "ok\n";
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    cannot_take_pointer(x);
    cannot_take_pointer(&x);  // fails to compile
}
```

Comment: Thanks sehe.  This is exactly what I needed.  Though I do not yet have access to C++0x I found an equivalent is_pointer in the boost library.

Comment: Indeed. Anywhere you find C++11 library parts missing, you can safely bet that boost has it (some compiler magic as macros, like BOOST_AUTO and BOOST_FOREACH). Of course there is BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this on your own (instead of using something like BOOST_STATIC _ASSERT), there are two or three basic tricks that are usually involved.

The first (and probably most important, in your case) is to use `sizeof` (with the result cast to `void`, usually) to get some code compiled *without* producing anything that will execute at compile time.

The second is to produce some code that's illegal under the right circumstances. One typical method is to create an array that will have a size equal to the value of some expression. If the expression has a value of 0, the array will have 0 size, which isn't allowed. Alternatively, if the size is one, it will be legal. The one problem with that is is the error message it produces is usually pretty meaningless -- it's hard to guess how "error: array must have positive size" (or something like that) relates to "the template parameter must not be a pointer".

To produce a more meaningful error message, you usually use a slightly different trick. In this case, a conversion from one class to another, that will fail if an expression is false, but succeed if it's true. One way to do that is like this:

```
template <bool>
struct check {  check(...);  };

template <>
class check<false> {};
```

The `check(...);` means *any* other type can (theoretically) be converted to a `check<true>` (but note that we only declare the function, never define it, so if you tried to *execute* such code, it wouldn't link). The lack of *any* conversion constructor in `check<false>` means attempting to convert anything else to a `check<false>` will always fail.

We can then use that with a macro something like this:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(expr, msg) {       \
    struct Error_##msg {};               \
    (void)sizeof(check<(expr)!=0>((Error_##msg))); \
}
```

You'd use this something like: `STATIC_ASSERT(whatever, parameter_cannot_be_a_pointer);`. That would expand to something like:

```
struct Error_parameter_cannot_be_a_pointer {};
(void)sizeof(check<(expr)!=0>(Error_parameter_cannot_be_a_pointer);
```

Then, if `expr` != 0, it'll attempt to convert Error_parameter_cannot_be_a_pointer to a `check<true>`, which will succeed.

On the other hand, if `expr` *does* equal 0, it'll attempt to convert to a `check<false>`, which will fail. We at least hope that when that happens, we get an error message something like this:

```
 error cannot convert:
     Error_parameter_cannot_be_a_pointer
 to
     check<false>
```

Obviously we'd like an even better message than that if we *could*, but even as it stands, that's not too terrible. You just have to ignore the "wrapping", and look at the name of the source type to get a pretty good idea of the problem.

Comment: ...to which a typical solution is to name the negative-length array something telling, like "int FUNCTION_DOES_NOT_ACCEPT_POINTERS[-1]", with the hope that the variable name will be printed as part of the compilation error.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: That can be useful, and sometimes works, but at least in my experience, compilers print out names far less often than types.

Comment: Note that this will give a bad error if you try to use the same error message multiple times.

Comment: @Xeo: It shouldn't. Note that the class being defined is in a block of its own, so two identical error messages will still produce separate classes in separate blocks.

Comment: @Jerry: Sorry, didn't see the curly braces. :)

Comment: Thanks Jerry.  Although I really was not looking to implement my own static assertion mechanism I did enjoy reading this accessible presentation.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a perfect case for `boost::disable_if`. Something like this should work.

```
template <class T>
void func(T x, typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_pointer<T> >::type* dummy = 0) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}


func(10); // works
func(std::string("hello")); // works
func("hello world"); // error: no matching function for call to 'func(const char [6])'
func(new int(10)); // error: no matching function for call to 'func(int*&)'
```

Comment: In C++11, `std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>`. Also, I'd put it as the return value, or another template argument.

Comment: Thanks Evan.  Unfortunately the function I want to guard is operator<< so I do not have the freedom to add an extra argument.

Comment: @John Yates: There are other ways to use `disable_if` besides adding another parameter. You should check out the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html

Comment: My reading was that disable_if could be applied either to a new argument or to the return expression.  Tacit was the assumption that the function's return type is dependent on the template parameter.  Unfortunately I am implementing a package with a streaming interface.  Stroustrup describes this pattern in great detail.  An important property of the put (<<) and get(>>) operators is that they return a reference to the stream, rather than a dependent type.  Hence I concluded that disable_if would not work in my setting.  Still, reading about disable_if did help me better understand SFINAE.